# Как скомпилировать проект в Unity для Android с Gradle?

Tags: android, unity3d, android-sdk, java

Создал приложение для Android с поддержкой AR в Unity, при попытке компиляции выдает ошибку. Gradle установлен, SDK и JDK тоже. Подскажите, как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался. Нужно было в Build System указать не Gradle, а Internal, и установить JDK 8.